# Weird converting NSString to int issue

Tags: ios, nsstring, timestamp

I'm converting an NSString to an int for a project, in order to compare time stamps. This is the response I get from my NSLog when i convert it.

```
Server Time Stamp = 1363032033711 AND Server Time Stamp CONVERTED: 2147483647
```

I'm using this code to convert it:

```
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", message];
NSArray *subString = [msg componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *timeStamp = [subString lastObject];
int serverTimeStamp = [timeStamp intValue];
NSLog(@"Server Time Stamp = %@ AND Server Time Stamp CONVERTED: %d", timeStamp, serverTimeStamp);
```

I'm not sure why the converted number is so weird, is it a problem with my code, or with converting strings to ints?

Comment: `NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", message];` - Oh God, why?

Comment: @H2CO3 That has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @MikeD However, it's something superfluous that decreases readability (and performance if called a zillion times per second). It should be pointed out as a piece of bad practice to be avoided.

Comment: @MikeD Although that may not be the cause of the problem, that usage of stringWithFormat: is pretty silly. And Mark, as for your problem, Google NSIntegerMax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1363032033711` is too big. It cannot be converted to an `int` (which appears to be 32 bits long on iOS). If you do a Google search for `2147483647`, you find out that it's the maximal value of a 32-bit signed `int`. Perhaps that's how `- [NSString intValue]` indicates if it found a number that's too large to convert.

Solution: use a wider number type and `NSScanner`:

```
NSScanner *scn = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[subString lastObject]];
long long serverTimeStamp;
[scn scanLongLong:&serverTimeStamp];
```

Comment: @Mark117 I know I am :P Thanks, no problem.

Comment: @HotLicks Blehh :D +1 for that.

Comment: @H2CO3 - I'm unfamiliar with the emoticon ":D+1".  Is that supposed to be drool coming out of the mouth?

Comment: @HotLicks Rather a tongue with a weird-shaped piercing.